# Get file size (FileLen() of a file that has unicode characters in the name [Excel VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I am trying to list the contents of a directory in Windows. All works as expected but when I try to get the file size of the files (`Debug.Print FileLen(filepath & filename)` using the function `FileLen()` I get an error 53 on the second file because it has a unicode character in the name (a fullwidth number sign U+FF03). Any ideas how to deal with this?

Content of the directory `c:\Z\Test\`:

```
1#.txt
2＃.txt
```

Note that the first file has a "normal" number sign and the second file name has a *fullwidth number sign* (U+FF03). Here the VBA Code which works fine without the second `Debug.Print`.

```
Sub ListFiles()
Dim filename As String
Dim filepath As String
filepath = "c:\Z\Test\"
filename = Dir(filepath)
Do While filename <> ""
   Debug.Print filename
   Debug.Print FileLen(filepath & filename)
   filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. VBScript objects are able to deal with non ASCII characters in the file name:

```
Sub ListFilesNonASCIIName()
   Dim FSOLibrary As Object, fldObj As Object, fsoFile As Object
   Dim foldPath As String
   Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    foldPath = "c:\Z\Test\"
    Set fldObj = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(foldPath)
    For Each fsoFile In fldObj.files
         Debug.Print fsoFile.Name, fsoFile.Size
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gecko Didn't the above code solve your problem? Did you find some time to test it?

Comment: I tested it and it works well, solving my problem.