I have an Error trapping problem in Access
'The code works as I need it to other than the the error trap "On Error GoTo ThusError" fails. I have set Tools\Options\General to "Break in Class Module" as recommended in https://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/VBA/BasicErrorHandling.asp#:~:text=Verify%20Error%20Trapping%20Setting&text=From%20the%20module%20editor%20(IDE,%22On%20Error%20Resume%20Next%22. I also tried "Break on Unhandled Errors" but both settings have no effect.'
         Sub ListFiles(fldObj As Object, Mask As String)

            Dim fl As Object 'File
            Dim db As DAO.Database
            Set db = CurrentDb
            Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
            Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("FileNames", dbOpenDynaset)
        
            For Each fl In fldObj.files
             
               For i = 1 To 16
                  Extn = Right(fl, i)
                  If InStr(Extn, ".") > 0 Then
                     Extn = Right(Extn, i - 1)
                     i = 16
                  End If
               Next i
               On Error GoTo ThisError
               If InStr(fl, "$") > 0 _
                  Or Extn = "lnk" _
                  Or Extn = "ppm" _
                  Or InStr(fl, ".") = 0 _
                  Or Len(Extn) > 4 _
                  Or Extn = "dat" _
                  Or CLng(fl.Size / 1024) < 64 _
                  Or Extn = "sst" _
                  Or Extn = "ldb" _
                  Or Extn = "log" _
                  Or Extn = "WMF" _
                  Or Extn = "json" Then
                     SetAttr fl, vbNormal
                     Kill fl
                     GoTo LoopOut
                  End If
         ThisError:
               If fl.Name Like Mask Then
                  rst.AddNew
                  rst("File").Value = Left(fl.Name, Len(fl.Name) - (Len(Extn) + 1))
                  If (CStr(Err.Number)) = 0 Then rst("ErrNum&Description").Value = " " Else 
                  rst("ErrNum&Description").Value = CStr((Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description)
                  rst("KB Size").Value = CLng(fl.Size / 1024) 
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432605/get-file-size-filelen-of-a-file-that'
    '-has-unicode-characters-in-the-name-exce'
                  rst("Ext").Value = Extn
                  rst("Home").Value = fldObj
                  rst.Update
               End If
               Err.Clear
         LoopOut:
            Next

      End Sub


Your code is riddled with errors. To begin with, variable fl is an object. The FOR...NEXT loop that searches for an extension will fail because you cannot reference part of an object with a keyword that is expecting a string, Right(fl, i) in this case. You need to reference a string property within fl. For example Right(fl.Name, i). That error will not be trapped because the On Error Goto ThisError has not yet been defined. You have the same string related issue with If InStr(fl, "$") > 0, InStr(fl, "."), SetAttr fl, vbNormal, Kill fl, and rst("Home").Value = fldObj. If (CStr(Err.Number)) = 0 should read If Err.Number = 0. There is no need to convert it to a string. The use of the Goto statement to control program flow should be avoided at all costs. Never ever use punctuation or spaces in field names. rst("ErrNum&Description") and rst("KB Size") is asking for no end of trouble.
You should also have Option Explicit as the first line in every module. This will force variable declarations and avoid syntax errors.
I have thrown together a revision of your code to give you an idea of where you should be heading and there is still much more room for improvement. It is NOT error free as the content of your objects is unknown and it has NOT been tested:
Option Explicit

Sub ListFiles(fldObj As Object, Mask As String)

  Dim fl   As Object 'File
  Dim db   As DAO.Database
  Dim rst  As DAO.Recordset
  Dim i    As Integer
  Dim Extn As String

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("FileNames", dbOpenDynaset)

  On Error GoTo ThisError

  For Each fl In fldObj.files

'    For i = 1 To 16
'      Extn = Right(fl, i)
'      If InStr(Extn, ".") > 0 Then
'        Extn = Right(Extn, i - 1)
'        i = 16
'      End If
'    Next i

    ' A simpler way of finding the extension
    i = InStrRev(fl.Name, ".")
    If i > 0 Then
      Extn = Right(Extn, i + 1)
    End If

    If InStr(fl.Name, "$") > 0 _
      Or Extn = "lnk" _
      Or Extn = "ppm" _
      Or InStr(fl.Name, ".") = 0 _
      Or Len(Extn) > 4 _
      Or Extn = "dat" _
      Or CLng(fl.Size / 1024) < 64 _
      Or Extn = "sst" _
      Or Extn = "ldb" _
      Or Extn = "log" _
      Or Extn = "WMF" _
      Or Extn = "json" Then

        SetAttr fl.Name, vbNormal
        Kill fl.Name

    End If

LoopOut:
  Next

  rst.Close

  Exit Sub

' Error handling
ThisError:

  If fl.Name Like Mask Then
    rst.AddNew
    rst("File").Value = Left(fl.Name, Len(fl.Name) - (Len(Extn) + 1))

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
      rst("ErrNum&Description").Value = " "

    Else
      rst("ErrNum&Description").Value = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
      rst("KB Size").Value = CLng(fl.Size / 1024)
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432605/get-file-size-filelen-of-a-file-that'
      '-has-unicode-characters-in-the-name-exce'
      rst("Ext").Value = Extn
      rst("Home").Value = fldObj.Home  '<<< Don't know what Home is.
    End If

    rst.Update

  End If
  Err.Clear

  ' The use of Resume here will let you keep processing all file names if an.
  ' error occurs. Remove it if you want the routine to end on the first error.
  Resume LoopOut

End Sub


The code I'm running originated from 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory' and all works wonderfully accept the line "On Error GoTo ThisError" has no effect and the error created does not pass to the line "ThisError:". I have set the Tools\Options\General to "Break on Unhandled Errors" and tried it also on "Break in Class Module" this too makes no impact and the error trap remains inoperative.
My thoughts were that this may be the result of the error being raised in a Class Module. If this is the case then I have no idea as to how to approach such a problem nor the ramifications of doing so. The logic behind my suspicions comes from reading ""Break on Unhandled Errors" works in most cases but is problematic while debugging class modules. During development, if Error Trapping is set to "Break on Unhandled Errors" and an error occurs in a class module, the debugger stops on the line calling the class rather than the offending line in the class. This makes finding and fixing the problem a real pain. We recommend using "Break in Class Modules" which stops on the actual crashing line." @ 'https://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/VBA/BasicErrorHandling.asp#:~:text=Verify%20Error%20Trapping%20Setting&text=From%20the%20module%20editor%20(IDE,%22On%20Error%20Resume%20Next%22.

This should be part of the question, not an answer. And please make it readable by inserting newlines.

Yes agreed it was a simple case of me misunderstanding the instructions. Sorry about that.

Please reformat your text so that reading is a charm.
Also, if this topic is no longer needed consider closing or deleting it. At least accept your own answer as solution.
